# Removing text with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dom, html

I am using the following code to hide certain text (2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013) from showing up in a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ($) {
var el = $("#right_side");
//replace(/word to remove/ig, "");  
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2009\)/ig, ""));
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2010\)/ig, ""));
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2011\)/ig, ""));
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2012\)/ig, ""));
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2013\)/ig, ""));
});
</script>
```

First of all how do I condense this code so that i'm using just the 1 el.html etc..

Secondly how to I fire this code first before the DOM is loaded? Currently there is a second or two that I can see the unwanted text before the code kicks in. This delay is also causing the adsense ads to disappear. I have this code positioned in the HEAD directly after JQUERY, which is first to load.

I have a live example of this [here](http://www.trailerstars.com). Look at the 'Latest Trailers' section on the right-hand-side column for where the code is targeting.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a regexp - `el.html(el.html().replace(/(20[\d\d]{2})/ig, '')`. Maybe have the container that contains the text hidden or `visibility: none`. Only when the replacement is done, bring it back into the view.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Unfortunately my knowledge of javascript is very limited as you are already aware of. :) How would I go about telling the container div show once the text was hidden? Thanks heaps. @Rishabh

Comment: Right after the replacement is done, you can do something like `$('.container').css('visibility', 'visible');` or `$('.container').css('display', 'block');` - whichever you prefer.

Comment: Do i include this code within the replace code? Such as:   `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ($) {
    var el = $("#right_side");
    //replace(/word to remove/ig, ""); 
 el.html(el.html().replace(/\(20[\d\d]{2}\)/ig, ''));$('"#right_side"').css('display', 'block');
});
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
el.html(el.html().replace(/\(2009|2010|2011|2012|2013\)/ig, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function ($) {
var el = $("#right_side");
//replace(/word to remove/ig, "");  
CleanUp(el,2009);
CleanUp(el,2010);

...
...
});
function CleanUp(el,value)
{
el.html(el.html().replace('/\(' + value + '\)/ig', ""));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace anything starting with 20 and ending in two digits, you can use the following. If this is being loaded in the header, you have to wait for the DOM to load.

```
el.html=el.html().replace(/\(20\d\d\)/g, '');
```

If you rather it be a true OR, you could keep repeating...

```
el.html=el.html().replace(/\((2009|2010|2011|2012|2013)\)/g, '');
```

Edit: Apparently this library can be used to modify the DOM as it loads for some browsers, could set a callback to the replacement for the proper CSS class - https://github.com/jamesallardice/Progressive.js